# How does SCSM Relate Affected Users to Service Requests?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, powershell, powershell-v4.0, scsm-2012

I'm using the built in SCSM cmdlets and the SMlets powershell module.  I'm able to query Service Requests, but I can't seem to figure out how to get the Affected User of a given Service Request.  I'm getting service requests in the following manner:

```
Import-Module SMlets -ErrorAction Stop

$SCSMclassSR = Get-SCSMClass -Name System.WorkItem.ServiceRequest
$SCSMobject = Get-SCSMObject -Class $SCSMclassSR
```

If you select any given ticket and run a `Get-Member` on it you can view the list of properties.  None of which are mapping back to the Affected User.  Thinking perhaps the ticket data is saved with the user object, I ran the following code:

```
$scsmuser = Get-SCSMObject -Class (get-scsmclass -name microsoft.ad.user) -filter "UserName -like <username>"
```

None of the properties there appear to map to any tickets (run a gm on it too).  Granted, this could be ignorance on my part and the method to produce the tickets just isn't aptly named or described.

I've tried looking at the [SMlets source code](https://smlets.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Main/Source/SMLets/SMLets/) to glean some insight, but I'm not a C# developer so some of it goes over my head.  I've also tried to get some understanding and help from the msdn page for [EnterpriseManagementObject Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg462058.aspx), but to no avail.

Hopefully there's a really simple solution to this and I'm just over thinking it.  But, **how do you get the Affected User for a SCSM ticket using powershell?**  Preferably a service request ticket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I kept digging and found a script online where someone wanted to find user email addresses for incidents.  I figured they'd have to find the user first (which would give me the AffectedUser), and I was right.  Here's the solution:

```
$SCSMclassSR = Get-SCSMClass -Name System.WorkItem.ServiceRequest
$SCSMobject = Get-SCSMObject -Class $SCSMclassSR

$affectedUserRelClass = Get-SCSMRelationshipClass System.WorkItemAffectedUser$

Foreach($SR in $SCSMobject){
        $affectedUser = Get-SCSMRelatedObject -SMObject $SR -Relationship $AffectedUserRelClass
        Add-Member -InputObject $SR -Name AffectedUser -Value $affectedUser.UserName -MemberType NoteProperty
}
```